# how to send request to ocpp1.6 charger using django channel server

Tags: python, django, django-channels, ocpp

I created a django web application and i use django channel to establish connection with ocpp1.6 charger. in consumers.py in receive_json function im receiving chargers requests and sending response successfully,

problem:
i need to send request to charger from my django server like remote start transaction request, how i can becoz in consumers.py file the receive function is only send response when they receive data

i want when a client from my front end click on start button then a request sent to charger for remote start transaction

Comment: Did you get to find solution?